# ARM Conditional Statements - Assembly in Raspberry pi

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, arm

What is the code below doing? I've added comments to make sense of it. But I'm having a hard time. To me it seems like user is asked to put an input and there's a compare if number is less than ASCII #48 then print nd: label with the return code of 10 and if it's greater than ASCII #57 it still says print nd: label but with a return code of 20.

```
        .global    _start
_start:
    MOV R0, #1          // R0 = 1
    MOV R2, #33         // R2 = 33
    MOV R7, #4          // R7 = syscall to write 
    LDR R1, =p          // load output p: to print "xxxxxxxxxxx"
    SWI 0           
    MOV R0, #0          // R0 = 0, stdin 
    MOV R2, #2          // R2 = 2 character
    MOV R7, #3          // R7 = syscall to read 
    LDR R1, =i          // load user input 
    SWI 0
    LDR R1, =i          // load R1, 
    LDR R2, [R1]        // load in R2, the address of R1 
    AND R0, R2, #255    // AND to convert in ASCII?
    CMP R0, #48         // compare to ASCII #48 (0, punctuation)
    BLT _l              // branch of less than to _l
    CMP R0, #57         // compare to ASCII #59 (9, number)
    BGT _g              // branch if greater than 
    SUB R0, R0, #48     // compare 
    BAL _exit
_l:
    MOV R0, #1
    MOV R2, #27
    MOV R7, #4
    LDR R1, =nd         // print nd: output 
    SWI 0
    MOV R0, #10         // return code 10
    BAL _exit
_g:
    MOV R0, #1
    MOV R2, #27
    MOV R7, #4
    LDR R1, =nd
    SWI 0
    MOV R0, #20         // return code 20
_exit:
    MOV R7, #1
    SWI 0

.data
p:
.ascii "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

nd:
.ascii "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"

i:
```

Comment: If between 48 and 57, then return negative 48.  Also, the code is buggy and depends on the tools. The 'i:' should define some space to store the result.  Also, no one uses `BAL`, they just type `B` for branch always.  Using constants like `SYS_WRITE` for the #4 would also make the code much more readable.  Also, populate, R0-R3 and then set R7 before the SWI to make the system call much clearer.  The comment '// compare' is wrong.

Comment: if the input was number a number, the return code is that number, otherwise its 10 or 20. "SUB R0, R0, #48" removes the ascii offset. Looks like a small program to be able to access user input in a shell, "xxxxx" will be replaced with the prompt (maybe that's why it's labeld "p"?), "yyyyy" will be replaced with an error-message